# Strange Function Behavior with Prototype and Event Listeners - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypejs, dom-events

> Original Modal

I want to use a universal `app` object. To this empty object I will add functions as needed. The issue is that some functions will need to all others within the app object.

So, my question is: how do I construct a large object without having to define all functions inside the object at the time of creation? I would like to split up the chunks of code to not have one astronomical long `.js` file.

There is a simple example of my original code:

```
var app = {
  tow: function () {
    return true;
  },
  one: function () {
    return this.tow();
  }
};

// app.one() => returns true
```

> Updated Modal

Here is something I found interesting. I was playing around with the `prototype` modal and discovered something strange. When I use this model I can add functions that can call other added functions. But, when I create an event listener it is unable to run the code. Can anyone explain why this is?

Modified code with unexpected result:

```
function modal () {}

modal.prototype.one = function () {
  return this.two();
};

modal.prototype.two = function () {
  return "cool";
};

modal.prototype.init = function () {
  document.getElementById('go')
    .addEventListener("click", this.one);
}

var app = new modal();
app.init();

// app.one() => returns true
// event listener => returns "TypeError: this.two is not a function"
```

JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/vureruziza/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Please ask only a single question per post.

Comment: "*how do I construct a large object without having to define all functions inside the object at the time of creation?*" - you don't have to. You can create functions that will use other functions that are not yet assigned. You just must not actually *call* any of those functions before everything is created.

Answer (score 0):

this.one called as you done refers to addEventListener function, not to your object. This will solve the issue

```
modal.prototype.init = function () {
  var self = this;
  document.getElementById('go')
    .addEventListener("click", function(){
      self.one()
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bind the click function with this cause the function will need the this context, not the window context. Then call your this.one function in de click handler.

```js
function modal () {}

modal.prototype.one = function () {
  return this.two();
};

modal.prototype.two = function () {
  return "cool";
};

modal.prototype.init = function () {
  document.getElementById('go')
   .addEventListener("click", function(e){ 
      console.log(this.one()) 
    }.bind(this));
    
/*
The following wil also be called but your return value 
of your this.one function won't be captured. But your code will run.

    .addEventListener("click", this.one.bind(this));
    
Try replacing it with the above and put a debugger statement in this.one 
and see that the code will actualy be ran, just not captured to output.
*/
}

var app = new modal();
app.init();

// app.one() => returns true
// event listener => returns "TypeError: this.two is not a function"
```

```html
<div id="go">go</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ES6 fat arrow function. Update `modal.prototype.init` as below -

```
modal.prototype.init = function () {
  document.getElementById('go')
    .addEventListener("click", () => this.one());
}
```

**Edit** - If you wanted to debug the issue, you could just `console.log` the `this` value in function `one` like so -

```
modal.prototype.one = function () {
  console.log(this);
  return this.two();
};
```

You will most likely see the `window` object. You will certainly not see the `modal` object.